# C++ transparent string memory compression

Tags: c++, string, compression

We have a long-running application (actually, a Windows service), whose footprint we like to keep as small as possible.

Our application needs to store some larger strings it needs to read only rarely (e.g. only every 30-60 minutes). We thought about compressing the strings in memory. The benefits of reduced RAM usage would certainly outweigh the CPU cycles required to compress/decompress in our use case.

**Is there a library that provides a compressed string class that transparently compresses anything written to it and automatically decompresses on read?**

We are using the STL with Boost. We would prefer not paging data out to disk.

Comment: This would be better posted to [softwarerecs.se], since recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I once saw a C++ stream wrapper for libz. What do you mean with "transparently"? It is called `std::string` but compresses contents internally? Or is it sufficient that that class has simply the same interface like `std::string`?

Comment: How large is "large"? It is not that difficult to write such a wrapper. But have you considered that [de]compression overhead could increase total memory consumption?

Comment: One thing you may have to consider is that some malloc implementations do not actually return freed memory to the operating system, because it would be hard to do so due to fragmentation. This may or may not apply to very large allocations. I am not sure about Microsofts standard library there, but in order for this to work, the memory for decompression may need a fancy allocator that allows you to actually return the memory, maybe using VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree, or by relying on a specific malloc implementation.

Comment: Another consideration is leveraging in-memory compression using zlib, [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/), etc. or even an in-memory database.

Comment: You can’t have a normal string interface: random access to the original string via automatic decompression would be ludicrously inefficient.

Comment: If you are accessing large chunks of memory once or twice an hour, it is almost certainly paged to disk by the OS. While the data continues to consume address space, it doesn't consume any RAM. Have you actually measured?